# Any Flaw?) If columns of a square matrix are linearly independent, A is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My strategy to prove this part is I assume columns of Matrix are linearly independent and A is not invertible,

$AX=V$ has non unique solutions, say $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$.

Then, There are two solutions $X_{1} \neq X_{2}$ such that $AX_{1}=V$ and $AX_{2}=V$. Then if follows that $A(X_{1}-X_{2})=0$.

From which we desire a series of linear combinations of [image]

It implies that each $\alpha_{i}$ is zero since vectors of A are linearly independent and thus $X_{1}=X_{2}$

Can I conclude from this result that A must have unique solution $X$ satisfying $AX=B$ and therefore $A$ is invertible?

Comment: You need to assume that this is a square matrix.

Comment: @landa Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If columns are lineraly independent $Ax=y$ is injective and surjective thus the transformation is invertible, that is exists $B=A^{-1}$ such that $x=By$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to emphasize that your matrix is a square matrix.

Otherwise speaking of inverse in problematic.

For square matrices your argument is valid, you are showing that there are no zero eigenvalues, thus the matrix is invertible.

Comment: I deal with the square matrices, and the problem is there is a flaw in this proof and i don't see which flaw this proof raises.

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: But, my prof said there is a flaw in this proof and I dont see which part of proof is wrong

Comment: Let me check your proof again and get back to you.

Comment: What   about your last Sigma notation. It seems that you need to be careful with your $a_n$ and $\alpha _n$

Comment: Or is it wrong to assume that there are two different solutions?

Comment: Not if you can get a contradiction which you did.

Comment: If matrix is not invertible, then there might be case that A does not have any solution?